# Javascript App with OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

You can implement the "Authorization Code Flow" in this situation?

A single page app in **www.app.com**

A REST backend in **www.backend.com**

Is possible to obtain via javascript an "authorization code" and then pass it to the "backend" for this get the "access token"?

Answer (score 2):

In theory, using the authorization code flow (or the hybrid flow) with a JS/mobile/desktop application is definitely possible, and you don't even need to store client credentials for that (you could, of course, but extracting them is so easy that it would be pointless).

Contrary to popular belief, client authentication is not required for "public" applications (i.e apps that cannot safely store their credentials, which includes JS apps) when using the authorization code flow:

> If the client type is confidential or the client was issued client
> credentials (or assigned other authentication requirements), the
> client MUST authenticate with the authorization server as described
> in Section 3.2.1.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3

> f the Client is a Confidential Client, then it MUST authenticate to the Token Endpoint using the authentication method registered for its client_id, as described in Section 9.

http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenRequest

In practice, I'm pretty sure most authorization/authentication servers will enforce client authentication when using the authorization code flow and will instead recommend using the implicit flow for public apps.

If your authorization server supports this scenario, using the authorization code flow in your JS app should be easy if you use `response_mode=query` (or better: `response_mode=fragment` as suggested by @Hans), since you can use your JS main page as the `redirect_uri` and use some JS to extract the authorization code from the query string or from the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

That is possible by setting the `redirect_uri` to somewhere in your SPA, pickup the `code` from the authorization response (using any of the methods described in [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter)) and pass it on to the backend in an application specific way. When using OpenID Connect there's the option to have the `code` delivered in the fragment of the `redirect_uri` which has some security advantages over having it delivered as a query parameter.

Comment: Hans, that solution is insecure? Why the only way that everyone mentions is the "implicit flow"? Thanks :)

Comment: Do you know a blog that explains how to use the "server flow" for a SPA?

Comment: having a token delivered to a Javascript SPA is inherently less secure than delivering it to the backend because no client secret can be involved; if you have server code that you can use (which makes your SPA not an SPA anymore), apply the regular Authorization Code grant